# Can someone explain group-ids in Neo4j CSV files headers?

Tags: neo4j

I couldn't find an explanation in the documentation..

What is the difference of using :

```
 orderId:ID
```

and

```
 orderId:ID(Order)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `(Order)` in the CSV header item `orderId:ID(Order)` specifies an [ID space](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/tools/import/file-header-format/#import-tool-id-spaces) named `Order`.

By default, the identifiers used in `ID` columns must be unique across all imported CSV files. But you can specify that the identifiers in a particular CSV file are only guaranteed to be unique within that file by specifying an ID space in its `ID` header item (as above). That same ID space name can be also be used in the header of relationship files to indicate the ID space for the start or end nodes (e.g., `START_ID(Order)`. or `END_ID(Order)`).